# What does it mean by "odds" and "edge" in probability/statistics?

Tags: probability, game-theory

I am trying to figure out the method of calculating `house edge` for example in the game of `Baccarat` [here](https://wizardofodds.com/gambling/house-edge/).

The probability of player winning is `44.6246609343597%` and the payout is 1 to 1. For house is `45.8597422632763%` and the payout is 0.95 to 1. (5% commission). What does it mean by `house edge` and how is it calculated?

**To be more specific**

**I know how to work out the probabilities here, I am asking how to work out the number `1.24%` of the house edge on the player.**

As a plus, how are the `STANDARD DEVIATION` calculated?

Thanks.

Comment: Usually edge is difference between true odds and pay out. https://www.thoughtco.com/understanding-the-house-edge-537607

Comment: Since each move in Baccarat is pre-determined (at least on the banker's side) it is probably easiest to calculate probabilities by sampling.

Comment: Worth noting:  I believe I worked it out once, and the preset bankers' moves are not strictly optimal (it was a long time ago so I am not sure of my recollection). That is, there are few instances where the banker is forced off of an optimal strategy.  That matters for this calculation as it will be necessary to construct the optimal strategy for the opponent.

Comment: @lulu Thanks. I know exactly how to work out the probabilities. My questions was about the `wording`.

Answer (score 0):

Edge = expected value of a bet from the house's perspective.

The expected value of a bet on "player" from the gambler's perspective (probability win * payout - probability lose * 1):

44.6246609343597 - 45.8597422632763 = -1.24%

For the house edge, we just need to flip the sign: 1.24%. Meaning, for every 100\$ wagered on player, the house is expected to win 1.24\$.

For a bet on "gambler":

45.8597422632763 * 0.95 - 44.6246609343597 = -1.06%